# How to make this work without global variable in R?

Tags: r, json, recursion

I am parsing some metadata containing json files to similar dataframes. I am using tidyjson. Finally i made it work like this:

```
append_arrays_and_objects <- function (tbl) {

  objs <- tbl %>%
    filter(is_json_object(.)) %>% gather_object %>%
    append_values_string

  arr <- tbl %>% 
    filter(is_json_array(.)) %>% gather_array %>%
    append_values_string

  if (nrow(objs) > 0) append_arrays_and_objects(objs)
  if (nrow(arr) > 0) append_arrays_and_objects(arr)
  print(objs)
  print(arr)
  res1 <- merge(objs,arr, all=TRUE)
  result <<- merge(result,res1, all=TRUE)
  result
} 

#parse microdata
result <- data.frame()

md <- dataHighest$JSON %>%
  enter_object(microdata) %>%
  append_arrays_and_objects 

rm(result)
```

It just bothers me that I can't make it work without the global dataframe `result`. When i tried it by returning any combination of local dataframes it always ends up with a dataframe with the "first level" depth dataframe.. I think when it has all the data collected i cannot seem to pass it back anymore. Should be trivial to solve?

Comment: perhaps I don't know enough about json objects but why can you not just return res1?

Comment: I tried that too. It loses all the nested data then.

Comment: Do a `merge` with the results of the recursive calls inside your `if` statements, instead of at the end.